# Trigger Jenkins to build when changes are pushed from git

Tags: git, github, jenkins, push

I am trying to get jenkins setup to start a build whenever a push is sent from my local branch to the remote branch.

I believe that I have setup all fields in the Jenkins browser IDE, yet no build is produced when I push to Jenkins.

Via http://blog.cloudbees.com/2012/01/better-integration-between-jenkins-and.html :

Configure System / Github Web Hook:
[image: Configure System / Github Web Hook]

Project / Configure / Build Triggers:

[image]

Comment: Where are you defining the repo? and how?

Comment: Is your Jenkins server publicly available? If so, why not have GitHub push instead of Jenkins poll.

Answer (score 1):

The check option on "Build when a change is pushed to GitHub" is not working. Although I found a workaround to poll for changes in git every 30 min. Monday through Friday using the "Poll SCM" option and cron input:

[image]